# Windows Service :No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I created windows application which have window service which Post data on web application and  runs every 60 min.i created windows setup for that. when i installed the setup on windows machine it is working fine but when i restart my windows machine it will showing me "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:15844" Error.

Here is trace log:
Inner Exception Type: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Inner Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:15844
Inner Source: System
Inner Stack Trace: 
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
Exception Type: System.Net.WebException
Exception: Unable to connect to the remote server
Source: Update Server Exception Entity-Units
Stack Trace: 
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at App.DataProvider.AppSync.UpdateServer(String jsonResult, String locationId, AppEntity AppEntity)

Comment: Just to see if i get it right. You app is a windows service that post data to a web application each 60 minutes? And after a reboot it wont work? The port 15844 seems kind of odd, my guess would be that the port is random and efter the reboot its a new port? Can you check that your web application is up and running and still listening to that port?

Comment: Yes, this is desktop application which post data to web application every 60 min. when i installed the software on the machine it will work fine (example:- if i continue run the application after install it and run it like 8 hour it will work every hour and post data on the web application ) but when i restart system it will show me error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:15844"

Comment: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" is normally because the port is closed, or the application is closed that normally hosts the port. I would try to examine the server with port 15844 instead of the client program.

Comment: I have found the solution. i am using windows service account = localsystem. whick i changed to network and its working fine without any issue